# How is that nth term is generalised

Tags: calculus

[image][image]

How this expansion is generalised to the nth term (see the last term)...i can't understand that how it has been done..
Please clearify to me 
Thanks in advance

Comment: At a first glance, it seems like the book is indeed not very clear about that ... I'm as baffled as you are!

Comment: They seem to have collected the $\sin$ and $\cos$ terms into a single $\sin$ term. Which is something you can do, as $A\sin(bx) + B\cos(bx) = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2}\sin(bx + C)$ for some $C$. It's "just" a matter of finding $A$, $B$ and $C$.

Answer (score 1):

Since differentiation swaps sines to cosines (give or take factors of $\pm b$ and scales exponentials, there are constants $c_n,\,s_n$ for which $y^{(n)}=e^{ax}(c_n\cos bx+s_n\sin bx)$. In particular $$c_0=0,\,s_0=1,\,c_{n+1}=ac_n+bs_n,\,s_{n+1}=as_n-bc_n.$$Can you solve that two-sequences recursion formula in your head? Probably not, so let's use a different parameterisation, $y^{(n)}=r_n e^{ax}\sin (bx+\phi_n)$. Now we're in business, because differentiating and cancelling $e^{ax}$ gives $$r_{n+1}\sin (bx+\phi_{n+1})=r_n (a\sin (bx+\phi_n)+ b\cos (bx+\phi_n))=r_n\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin (bx+\phi_n+\theta),$$where the angle $\theta$ satisfies $\cos\theta =a,\,\sin\theta=b$ so $\tan\theta=\frac{b}{a}$. Now, if I'm being a pedant we should write $\theta=\operatorname{atan2}(b,\,a)$ rather than $\theta=\arctan\frac{b}{a}$, but presumably the question assumes $a,\,b>0$. Anyway, the recursion is much easier now:$$r_0=1,\,\phi_0=0,\,r_{n+1}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}r_n,\,\phi_{n+1}=\phi_n+\theta.$$The desired result follows immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Using the de Moivre's identity we have

$$
y = \frac{e^{(a+ib)x}-e^{(a-ib)x}}{2i}= \frac{1}{2i}(1,-1)\cdot(e^{(a+ib)x},e^{(a-ib)x})
$$

then

$$
y^{(k)} = \frac{1}{2i}((a+ib)^k, -(a-ib)^k)\cdot (e^{(a+ib)x},e^{(a-ib)x}) = \frac{1}{2i}\rho^k(e^{i k \phi},-e^{-i k \phi})\cdot (e^{(a+ib)x},e^{(a-ib)x})
$$

with

$$
\begin{cases}
\rho = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\\
\phi = \arctan(\frac b a)
\end{cases}
$$

and finally

$$
y^{(k)} = \rho^k e^{ax}\sin(bx+k\phi)
$$

NOTE

Here $(u,v)\cdot(m,n) = um+vn$